# how is envp argument passed to execve system call?

Tags: linux, c

Suppose I call

```
int execve(const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const envp[])
```

where I `malloc`ed memory for `envp`, then how does the program `filename` access the contents of that array when `execve` wipes out all the previous memory (including heap)?

Comment: The most obvious answer would be that `execve` copies both argv[] and envp[] into another area (possibly kernel memory) _before_ it discards the rest, wouldn't it?

Comment: There's no great mystery here; the kernel just copies out and preserves both `argv` and `envp` into somewhere, then makes them available to the new process image. Exactly where and how it does this is an implementation detail, which shouldn't be of interest unless you're doing something deep and magical, or kernel hacking.